# Connecting two blogs in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have 2 blogs using wordpress, for example the blog A provide ecommerce that often update and the other blog called blog B used for news that the content updated from blog B for example.
the matter is how to make recently updated content in blog A displayed in blog B? or there any plugin or theme to do that??

Comment: Are they two separate Wordpress installations or Multisite blogs?

Comment: multisite blog, maybe? for example i want every posting in blog A, there automatically display post title and some excerpt of blog A in blog B.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this work with WordPress Plugin name "Push Syndication" download that plugin from here http://wordpress.org/plugins/push-syndication/ . I'm sure this will solve your problem and perform same task which you want to do.